# Android OneSignal - Bring app to front after clicking notification

Tags: android, onesignal

I'm using OneSignal for my Android notifications. I am able to receive the notification and start an activity in my own NotificationOpenedHandler():

```
String code = payload.additionalData.getString(Cons.KEY_CODE);
if(code.equalsIgnoreCase(Cons.NOTIFICATION_DETAIL_SCREEN)) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

The problem is that if I'm in another app and I click the notification, my app will not be brought to the front. Although when I navigate to my app, the activity I specified above has launched as intended.

I've disabled the default launcher in my manifest as well:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationOpened.DEFAULT" android:value="DISABLE" />
```

Anyone know why my app is not being brought to front?

Comment: try setting appropriate flags with intent. I am using  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT); and it works for me

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in my case. Notification is dismissed, but my app is not brought to front.

Comment: is  DetailActivity your launcher activity ? or its a class within your app ?

Comment: Detail activity is not my launcher, it is a class within my app.

Comment: even i am using OneSignal but I use deep link schema to open my activities. You can give it a try & startActivity call should be preceded by context which is not there in your mentioned code. You can try that too - i.e getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent); without that startActivity won't get resolved.

Comment: Aight cool that worked. If you want to throw it into an answer I'll give you credit for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Try setting appropriate flags with intent `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);`
2. StartActivity call should be preceded by context which is not there in your mentioned code. You can try that too - i.e `getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);` without that startActivity won't get resolved

Answer (score 0):

You need to put this in your intent before start the activity:

intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

Then start the activity.

Comment: No, this doesn't work in my case. The notification is dismissed and my app is not brought to the front.